# Help with URL Regex

Tags: regex, coldfusion

I have the following code to format a URL:

```
<cfset textToFormat = ReReplaceNoCase( textToFormat, '((http(s)?://)?((www\.)?\w+\.\w{2,6}))', '<a class="actionLink" href="http://\4">\1</a>', "ALL" ) />
```

The problem is with complex URLS it is not working properly, for example this URL:

```
http://refer.ccbill.com/cgi-bin/clicks.cgi?CA=111111&PA=222222
```

Also a URL like this isn't working:

```
http://secure.someurl.com/track/AAAAAA4wLjAuMC4w
```

Please could someone help me with a RegEx that could be used for all URLS.

Thanks

Comment: in your case, i think there is no universal regex expression. I would try to split a link by specific symbols. for example split by / and then try to split last item by ? . well you get a array but it will be more universal than regex. I don't know regex very well, but I think you will not be able to write universal expression

Comment: Try http://regexlib.com/DisplayPatterns.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.cflib.org/udf/ActivateURL

Comment: Thanks - this is the best of the lot and seems to be working for all cases except site.example.com which is not a trainsmash! Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

How about :

search pattern :

```
(?:https?://)?(((\w+\.)+\w{2,6})(/.*)?)
```

replace

```
<a class="actionLink" href="http://\2">\1</a>
```

Comment: Hi M42 - thanks - that works for the links I provided, however the simple links such as www.mysite.com don't work now.

Comment: @Cheeky: see my updated answer, make the last part `/.*` optionnal : `(/.*)?`

Comment: Thanks - we are almost there now "h-t-t-p://www.mysite.com" works properly (ignore the dashes, it was the only way I could add the http part without stackoverflow parsing it) , but not "www.mysite.com". I think we now need to make the http optional perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

You could use this expression:

```
(https?://)?(([a-z\d.-]+)(/.*)?)
```

and use it like:

```
<a class="actionLink" href="http://\2">\3</a>
```

A simple tests:

`http://secure.someurl.com/track/AAAAAA4wLjAuMC4w` gives `<a class="actionLink" href="http://secure.someurl.com/track/AAAAAA4wLjAuMC4w">secure.someurl.com</a>`

`http://refer.ccbill.com/cgi-bin/clicks.cgi?CA=111111&PA=222222` gives `<a class="actionLink" href="http://refer.ccbill.com/cgi-bin/clicks.cgi?CA=111111&PA=222222">refer.ccbill.com</a>`

`secure.someurl.com/track/AAAAAA4wLjAuMC4w` gives `<a class="actionLink" href="http://secure.someurl.com/track/AAAAAA4wLjAuMC4w">secure.someurl.com</a>`

and finally `refer.ccbill.com` gives `<a class="actionLink" href="http://refer.ccbill.com">refer.ccbill.com</a>`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that may work for you. First, linkify URLs beginning with either `http://`, `https://` or `www.` like so:

```
<cfset textToFormat = ReReplaceNoCase( textToFormat,
    '((https?://|www\.)[-A-Z0-9+&@#/%?=~_|$!:,.;]*[A-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|$])',
    '<a class="actionLink" href="\1">\1</a>',
    "ALL" )
/>
```

Next fix the invalid links created by the first step. (the URLs beginning with `www.` need an `http://` prefix):

```
<cfset textToFormat = ReReplaceNoCase( textToFormat,
    'href="www\.',
    'href="http://www.',
    "ALL" )
/>
```

Note that this is untested as I have no access to ColdFusion. Also, their regex syntax is poorly documented, so this solution uses only very rudimentary expressions.

**Caveats:** Linkifying URLs is difficult to do well and there are quite a few cases where this solution will fail. See: [The Problem With URLs](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/10/the-problem-with-urls.html) by Jeff Atwood, and [An Improved Liberal, Accurate Regex Pattern for Matching URLs](http://daringfireball.net/2010/07/improved_regex_for_matching_urls) by John Gruber and [URL Linkification](http://jmrware.com/articles/2010/linkifyurl/linkify.html) by yours truly for more information on converting URLs to links.

Answer (score 0):

your regex only evaluetsn urls which are this long:

```
http://secure.someurl.com
```

If you whant to evaluete the part after the url like

```
/track/AAAAAA4wLjAuMC4w
```

you have to append something like "\.*" (withaout the Quotes) to the end of the Regex, so it should be

```
'((http(s)?://)?((www\.)?\w+\.\w{2,6})\.*)'
```

(I havent tested it)

Regards,
Stefan

Comment: Hi Stefan - i think you meant a forward slash and not a backslash? As in "/.*"  Assuming that's what you meant, the Regex is working a lot better. However it still splits into two, like 

http://secure.
<a class="actionLink" href="http://someUrl.com">someUrl.com/track/AAAAAA4wLjAuMC4w </a>

Comment: The backslash is to escape the period which is used in Regular Expressions to match any single character

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try

```
(http|https|ftp)\://([a-zA-Z0-9\.\-]+(\:[a-zA-Z0-9\.&amp;%\$\-]+)*@)*((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]{1}[0-9]{2}|[1-9]{1}[0-9]{1}|[1-9])\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]{1}[0-9]{2}|[1-9]{1}[0-9]{1}|[1-9]|0)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]{1}[0-9]{2}|[1-9]{1}[0-9]{1}|[1-9]|0)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]{1}[0-9]{2}|[1-9]{1}[0-9]{1}|[0-9])|localhost|([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)*[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.(com|edu|gov|int|mil|net|org|biz|arpa|info|name|pro|aero|coop|museum|[a-zA-Z]{2}))(\:[0-9]+)*(/($|[a-zA-Z0-9\.\,\?\'\\\+&amp;%\$#\=~_\-]+))
```

Comment: Wow - what a long expression. Unfortunately that did not work. Not too close either.

Answer (score 0):

http://regexlib.com/DisplayPatterns.aspx will be lifesaver for me in most of the regex requirement.

[Try this](http://regexlib.com/%28A%28iuvFDYZZoRvnYAkzVEyH06X8dZgjge-YQXUMK_jk2d0EKLzBiYfvtEpOXxpef-CSomzE97pzzr7w07-6bBkLq_3khbk2seUdLY9ZMfI7X_hmm6O5rfZrFjYTgmuKYinzK_aai_9aLtFuccmdyPk3uryVs-ZFP39aR369eEaRnwnd_R2k3Eepvk9rmOFf6u3i0%29%29/REDetails.aspx?regexp_id=501)